# Define custom decorator like staticmethod

Tags: python, pylint, factory-boy

I use [factory-boy](https://pypi.org/project/factory-boy/) package and [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) for static linting. For the following code the linter emits the `no-self-argument` error.

```
import factory
from factory import Factory, Faker

class MyTestFactory(Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = dict

    a = Faker("pyint")
    b = Faker("pyint")

    @factory.lazy_attribute
    def a_and_b(obj):  # <-- no-self-argument here
        return obj.a + obj.b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    O1 = MyTestFactory.build()
    print(f"dbg: {O1=}")
```

> example2.py:12:4: E0213: Method should have "self" as first argument (no-self-argument)

I don't want to hide the message completely. But instead, I'd like to tell pylint that the `@factory.lazy_attribute` decorator behaves just like the `@staticmethod` builtin, so the method requires one argument less. Is it possible? Is there a special setting in pylintrc that is responsible for declarations of static methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.lazy_attribute):

> This decorates an instance method that should take a single argument, self; the name of the method will be used as the name of the attribute to fill with the return value of the method:

That means you should name your argument `self` instead of `obj`

Comment: Well, in my mind, the first argument belonged to the MyTestFactory class, I thought the method got instance of already constructed model.